# What is a good Configuration for distributed Spring Boot system with 36 downloaders through ssh tunnels

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, ssh, hikaricp

I've created a Java Spring Boot application that launches 36 downloader droplets on digital ocean, which ssh tunnel to a database CPU Optimized droplet and downloads from an API into the database.

I've configured hikari as follows towards less pooling connections assuming the database may have trouble with too many and thinking they might not be required.

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=5
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=200000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=1800000
spring.datasource.hikari.validationTimeout=100000
```

I'm wondering if those settings may or may not be recommended and why. I've reduced the maximumPoolSize to 5 however I haven't found much information on whether that is considered too small for Java Spring Boot Application to run effectively.

Given each downloader is storing data in the database sequentially do I need to have more than a few pooling connections on each downloader?

I've configured the maximum connections in mysql to 250 and the maximum ssh connections on the database server to 200. I note that 114 sshD processes are created on the server. Can a server handle that many ssh tunneling connections?

Do you forsee any problems with this kind of distributed setup with Spring boot? One thing I have had to do before adjusting to these settings is place retry connection code around each database connection to prevent disconnection errors.

Thanks
Conteh

Comment: You may wish to consider getting 1 working, then 2, then 3 until you have most of the surprises covered.  Why would you knowingly try to push 250 connections into the SSH that is configured for 200?

Comment: @wilson-hauck oh I thought the ssh tunnel would be 1 per server not one per database connection. That's good advice.

Comment: @wilson-hauck minimum 2 pooling connections thus far was required to get the application to work without a jdbc connection error. Thanks